# 301 redirect specific URLS if ?noRedirect not in URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm running a wordpress installation and want to move specific feeds off-site. I've already got most of the technology down, but here's the problem. I want the following URL:

```
http://www.csicon.net/g/feed
```

to redirect to

```
http://feed.mesr.it/g
```

But if the URL comes in like this:

```
http://www.csicon.net/g/feed?noRedirect
```

I don't want it to redirect but load the original. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The `.htaccess` file on `http://www.csicon.net/` would contain:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^\/g\/feed$ http://feed.mesr.it/g [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** It has not been tested, but you get the idea.

Later Edit: Also, this can be done in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)csicon\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)noRedirect [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/feed/?$ http://feed.mesr.it/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```